# AnkhSVN + Visual Studio 2013 Preview cannot set up - loading hangs

Tags: ankhsvn, visual-studio-2013

Using:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Preview Version 12.0.20623.01
  Update
- AnkhSVN 2.5.12116

I've:

- enabled the plugin in the Tools->Options
- added project to svn outside of VS, using TortoiseSVN GUI.

When I start VS, go to:

- File->Subversion->Open from subversion,
- add the svn URL:

  https://myserver.com/svn/repo/project

and then the dialog hangs, just saying:

*loading    (and showing the spinner, as if it is actually loading)*

No files are offered. Interestingly, if I open the URL combobox, it shows many different paths that I have in my repo, e.g.

- https://myserver.com/svn/repo/projectA
- https://myserver.com/svn/repo/projectB
- https://myserver.com/svn/repo/projectC

but which ever I one I choose, the endless "loading" occurs.

I've tried clearing the auth cache in AnkhSVN, I've imported the certificate from the https server on my win machine and so on.
TortoiseSVN works fine, and I can see the repo from Google Chrome.

Also, View->Repository Explorer hangs, showing spinner image forever.

Thanks,

Igor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you see when you type `ping myserver.com` in a command prompt. If you don't see a ping to an 12.34.56.78 like address, but to some '2001:888:0:7::77' style address your server most likely resolves to an ipv6 address before it resolves to an ipv4 address. (Note that `localhost` has this problem)

Subversion 1.8 switched to a new http implementation and this implementation currently doesn't try to connect to further addresses resolved by the DNS resolver.

The problem is that many Subversion servers don't listen to ipv6 connections yet, while by using the machine name as a service name you tell your http client (in this case Subversion) that your server does support ipv6.

Comment: It appears that's not the complete story, but at least it has unjammed me so that I've managed to checkout the project from the repo.
I did try with IPv4 (though I'm not happy with that - our server uses DHCP) and then, at least, a dialog poped up, asking me to accept certificate and give credentials.
But then it got stuck again, saying <Repository moved permanently to 'https://myserversdom​ainname/svn/'; please relocate>.
(BTW, it gets this URL list from the registry, I've had to regedit them).
So no luck from the File->Open from subversion

Comment: ...continued...
But I've managed to checkout the project from View->Repository explorer and then plain old File->Open project
Thanks Bert.